# Ollydbg - automatically add hardware breakpoint when step over

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint

I put INT3 breakpoint and starting the program. The OllyDbg break at the breakpoint, but when I step over, the OllyDbg put a hardware breakpoint. (Yesterday not happened in OllyDbg, but today during training it happened.)

**ٍEdit :** A red square usually occurs when step over, but goes to the next line immediately. But in this call, when i click F8 to step over, the program has stopped and no longer works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is The Default Behavior for almost every Debugger.
you might not have noticed it when the Function Returned Quickly
you should always see a red flicker on every **F8 (StepOver)**  on a call

it is an internal breakpoint set by ollydbg /any debugger and handled by ollydbg / almost all debugger

how would a debugger know to stop where after executing unknown instructions inside a call

see a gif for the flicker when doing f8 which executes the return silently
and no red flicker if you step in with f7

[image]

if the program stopped working it might have an anti-debugging trick inside the call try stepping in instead of step over  of follow the call set a breakpoint deep inside the function and check

Comment: Thank you very much, yes you are right. but in this specific CALL the ollyDbg stops, and all buttons not working, i also edit the post. please check it.

Comment: But, this call works good on windows XP, i mean after F8 on this call, i can step over to another instructions. Today this problem happened, yesterday works well.

Comment: @Jason. Try deleting the `.udd` and `.bak` files that OllyDbg creates when debugging an executable.

Comment: as @fpmurphy commented try deleting the udds